# Android Record Count Toast Message?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an App I would like to cripple by allowing only 5 records to be shown when doing a query.... The following is the code I'm using within the DataBaseHelper.java for this and it works great for what I need........It returns only 5 records in DESC order by KEY_RECORD1

My question is I would like implement a Warning message in the form of a Toast when this 5 Record limit it reached.....

So when you Add the Sixth Record you would get....Example Toast: Limit of 5 Records has been reached!

```
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {
    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_RECORD1, KEY_RECORD2,
                    KEY_RECORD3}, null,
            null, null, null, KEY_RECORD1 + " DESC", "5");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (fetchAllNotes().getCount() >= 5){
   //Toast.makeText...
}
```

to avoid extra request and improve perfs, you could do that once, to retrieve the number of records, and increment that counter each time you do an insertion.